# What is the requirements from an optical lab in terms of darkness

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

I am characterizing an optical lab and would like to know therefore what are the requirement from a standard optical lab in terms of ambient luminescence. In other words how dark should an optical lab be. The lab I am talking about should fit for experiments of photoluminescence and Raman spectroscopy.

Comment: You need to know what the expected signal levels from your experiment are, and calculate the acceptable SNR.  Hey, it's not Rocket Surgery!

Comment: I'm assuming you can probably do the kinds of calculations Carl is speaking of and that you want a more "what kind of light proofing hardware is needed" kind of answer. Because until you measure in detail (you will have to), you can calculate all you like, but you won't have a clue what it means compared to the kind of light levels you'll get in various kinds of buildings (especially since the eye is so autogaining). Do you want to estimate equipment needs for budgetting, or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

As @Carl mentioned in the comment (with a bit more elaboration), you need to determine this by a review of the literature and experimentally:

1. determine what the expected signal levels for your experiment will be, this can be achieved in the crucial literature review of previous similar work.  This will effectively set a theoretical baseline of what values to expect.  This prior research will also provide an indication of the expected range of measurements.
2. Determine what level of SNR ([signal to noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)) would be acceptable for your experiment. This could also be determined by research also.
3. Measure the current light levels that currently exist when you have the experiment setup. Either do a [sensitivity analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) and/or some preliminary testing to determine the SNR that occurs within your measurements - from then, adjust the light level accordingly if possible, or determine a correction for the ambient light (see the 1st example reference below).

*Some research that may be relevant (as I am not privy to the details of your research):*

1. [In-situ photoluminescence measurements during MOVPE growth of GaN
   and InGaN MQW structures](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022024814008380) (Prall et al. 2015), explain the
   experimental procedures that were

> employed to reduce unwanted light from other sources (thermal origin, **ambient light**)

2. [Selecting an Excitation Wavelength for Raman Spectroscopy](http://www.horiba.com/fileadmin/uploads/Scientific/Documents/Raman/Specy_Workbench_Selecting_Excitation_Wavelength_for_Raman.pdf)
   (Tuschel, 2016) - discusses a method how to achieve an optimal SNR.
3. A study in the European Journal of Mineralogy, "[Restricted access
   Gated Raman spectroscopy: potential for fundamental and applied
   mineralogy](http://eurjmin.geoscienceworld.org/content/21/1/33)" (Gaft and Nagli, 2009) is about how the authors

> demonstrate how a pulsed UV laser and time-resolved detection methods allow discrimination of Raman signals from strong luminescence background light